# Wordpress loop to filter out by meta

Tags: wordpress, loops, filter, meta-tags

This kind of follows on from a previous question where JanW : http://bit.ly/VQy9hb

I'm trying to hide posts that contain certain meta data, in this case meta_name = "smartPrivate".

The function below works but unfortunately also affects the menu loop (it just disappears).

Does anyone know how I can hide these posts from appearing in all loops but not affect the menu (and who knows what else...)

Thanks in advance
Rob

```
function hide_some_posts( $query ) {

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(

            array(
                  'key' => 'smartPrivate',
                  'value' => 'smartPrivate_loggedIn',
                  'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                  'key' => 'smartPrivate',
                  'value' => 'smartPrivate_loggedInMentors',
                  'compare' => '!='
            )

        ));
    }

  return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_some_posts' );
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be a better idea, to correct each loop (or one loop, depentds on theme) - and to set there exclusion of this meta? Or You just need to do it globally in function.php?

Comment: Hi Marcin - I'm building a framework with some core functions. I'd like our front end guys to be able to template the site without touching the loops at all. Functions.php is called even from the child theme so seems the best place to do it. That said - if I can't get it working I'll be adding this function to the pre-post hook I think. Unfortunately that means I need to trace them all, single, post-archive, pages etc.

Comment: @rob_was_taken I deleted my answer. I don't know what's going on, perhaps deleting it will increase the chance of somebody else answering.

Comment: @Calle - calling it in the traditional way, details below: `wp_nav_menu( array(

   'theme_location' => 'primary',
   'container_class' => 'nav-collapse collapse',
   'menu_class' => 'nav'

   ) );`

Comment: Hey @Calle - it looks like your answer was correct but the syntax slightly incorrect (for functions.php). It simply needed `$query->is_main_query()` and it seems to be working. Happy to give you the cred if you want to put your answer back? Failing that I'll just add the answer myself to help others.

Comment: @rob_was_taken Oh!!! That makes sense now. Thank you for telling me this. I undeleted my answer, and corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that it affects other queries than the main query, if I understand your situation correctly. This is pretty much why [is_main_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) exists. So try this:

```
function hide_some_posts( $query ) {


    if (!is_user_logged_in() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(

            array(
                  'key' => 'smartPrivate',
                  'value' => 'smartPrivate_loggedIn',
                  'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                  'key' => 'smartPrivate',
                  'value' => 'smartPrivate_loggedInMentors',
                  'compare' => '!='
            )

        ));
    }

  return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_some_posts' );
```

Comment: Hey Calle, thanks for the reply. I'm afraid that didn't fix it. It still breaks the WP nav menu? Even though other posts (that make it through the check) are showing in the main loop the menu disappears regardless.

Comment: That beats me. Also, I looked at the source code and wp_nav_menu doesn't really any query object (other than for adding some classes, to indicate if a page is the current one and so on). So I don't see why it's affected. Do you have debug mode on?

Comment: Yes, debug on, no errors or warnings @Calle. I wonder if I should isolate it using a different hook?

Comment: It's the right hook... how do you use wp_nav_menu? Do you provide a theme_location or something else?