# WordPress exclude post in archive by meta-value

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom archive page set up in WordPress that displays my custom posts.  I would like to exclude custom posts with a specific meta value (eg. meta-value='sold' or meta-value='expired').

I've looked at the following questions and they didn't work for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841377/filtered-custom-post-types-archive) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220461/wordpress-loop-to-filter-out-by-meta)

Here's the code I was trying to work with but I kept getting a parse error:

```
function my_meta_remove($query){
    if($query->is_archive) {
        $query->set('meta__not_in', array(sold,expired);
    }
    return $query;
    }

add_action("pre_get_posts","my_meta_remove");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you re missing `)`

change

`$query->set('meta__not_in', array(sold,expired);`

to this

`$query->set('meta__not_in', array(sold,expired));`

**EDIT**

`meta__not_in` doesn't exist, instead you need to use comparison and keys for each meta field (insert instead of `key_name`)

```
function my_meta_remove($query){
if($query->is_archive) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(

        array(
              'key' => 'key_name',
              'value' => 'sold',
              'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
              'key' => 'key_name',
              'value' => 'expired',
              'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )

    ));
}
return $query;
}

add_action("pre_get_posts","my_meta_remove");
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my plugin parse error.  However, the code doesn't do what I intended.  My posts with the above mentioned meta-value still appear on my archive page.

Comment: Plugin showed no errors but my site is now showing **Fatal error:** Function name must be a string

Comment: It says **21** 'return $query($args);'

Comment: sorry bout that... try now